# Apache Internal Server Error without log entry

Tags: apache

Are there cases where the Apache2 HTTP Server responds with an internal server error (Response code 500), yet does NOT write an entry into the server's error log file?
I experience such a case and have no idea what's going on. I already checked that the server generally logs errors by requesting a badly formed php script.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4731364/399105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mismatching versions of php and php-mssql caused this.

Comment: Not a solution to the problem at all.

Comment: I'm not even using mysql.

Comment: I didnt either m8.