# Where can I find error log files for PHP?

Tags: php, logging, centos, suphp

Where can I find error log files?

I need to check them for solving an internal server error shown after installing [suPHP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SuPHP).

Comment: It depends on your logging settings :) CO

Comment: my server is centos but it doesnt show anything under var/log/httpd

Comment: Check if [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) path is set in php.ini. If not set it will be usually logged in the web server's error log.

Comment: Look for `error_log` in `php.ini`, if you use `php-fpm`, you might also wanted to check `error_log` in php-fpm conf file

Comment: This is a super FAQ. A candidate for the canonical question: *[Where does PHP store the error log? (php5, apache, fastcgi, cpanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/)*. The title is somewhat specific, but the answers are certainly not (not all of them).

Answer (score 30):

You can use [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) to find open logfiles on your system. lsof just gives you a list of all open files.

Use [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for "log" ... use grep again for "php" (**if the filename contains the strings "log" and "php" like in "php_error_log" and you are the root user you will find the files without knowing the configuration**).

```
lsof | grep log

... snip
gmain     12148 12274       user   13r      REG              252,1    32768     661814 /home/user/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-11ab0393.log
gmain     12148 12274       user   21r      REG              252,1    32768     662622 /home/user/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-56222fe2.log
gvfs-udis 12246             user  mem       REG              252,1    55384     790567 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd-login.so.0.7.1
==> apache 12333             user  mem       REG              252,1    55384     790367 /var/log/http/php_error_log**
        ... snip
```

> 

```
lsof | grep log | grep php

**apache 12333             user  mem       REG              252,1    55384     790367 /var/log/http/php_error_log**
... snip
```

Also see this article on finding open logfiles: *[Find open logfiles on a Linux system](http://slash4.de/blog/howto/find-log-file-location-of-linux-process-with-lsof.html)*

Answer (score 16):

It works for me. How can we log all PHP errors to a log file?

Just add the following line to file */etc/php.ini* to log errors to specified file – file */var/log/php-scripts.log*

```
vi /etc/php.ini
```

Modify the *error_log* directive:

```
error_log = /var/log/php-scripts.log
```

Make sure *display_errors* is set to Off (no errors to end users):

```
display_errors = Off
```

Save and close the file. Restart the web server:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

How do I log errors to syslog or Windows Server Event Log?

Modify *error_log* as follows:

```
error_log = syslog
```

How can we see logs?

Login using ssh or download a log file /var/log/php-scripts.log using SFTP:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/php-scripts.log
```

Comment: Why should I make sure display_errors is off? Surely this shouldn't affect error logging, does it?

Comment: As stated in the answer, `display_errors` determines whether errors are displayed *to the end-user* (e.g. on the rendered webpage), so no, it doesn't affect logging.  http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: There is no error_log in php.ini for xammpp. Where do I find this?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what OS you are using and which web server.

On Linux and Apache, you can find the Apache *error_log* in folder */var/log/apache2/*.

Comment: under /var/log there is no any folder or files named apache2 or apache. My server is centos - apache

Comment: under /var/log/httpd ? You can config the log location of apache in the apache.conf file. this should be located somewhere at /etc/httpd/

Answer (score 6):

On [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) with [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) installed, my logs were in:

```
/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```

To watch: `tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`

Answer (score 6):

This will definitely help you,

*[Enable PHP error logging](https://davidwinter.me/enable-php-error-logging/)*

**Or**

In *php.ini* (`vim /etc/php.ini` *or* `sudo vim /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini`)

```
display_errors = Off

log_errors = On

error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log
```

Make the log file, and writable by user *www-data*:

```
sudo touch /var/log/php-errors.log

/var/log/php-errors.log

sudo chown <owner>:www
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a preferable answer in most use cases, because it allows you to decouple execution of the software from direct knowledge of the server platform, which keeps your code much more portable. If you are doing a lot of *cron* or *[CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)*, this may not help directly, but it can be set into a configuration at web runtime that the cron and CGI scripts pull from to keep the log location consistent in that case.

---

You can get the current log file assigned natively to PHP on any platform at runtime by using:

```
ini_get('error_log');
```

This returns the value distributed directly to the PHP binary by the web server, which is what you want in 90% of use cases (with the glaring exception being CGI). CGI will often log to this same location as the HTTP web server client, but not always.

You will also want to check that it is writeable before committing anything to it to avoid errors. The configuration file that defines its location (typically either file *apache.conf* globally or *vhosts.conf* on a per-domain basis), but the configuration does not ensure that file permissions allow write access at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I am using **CentOS 6.6** with **Apache** and for me error log files are in:

```
/usr/local/apache/log
```

Comment: Some [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) installations on Linux may use `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Answer (score 1):

**For Unix CLI users**:

Most probably the *error_log* ini file entry isn't set. To verify:

```
php -i | grep error_log
// error_log => no value => no value
```

You can either set it in your *php.ini* CLI file, or just simply quickly pipe all **[standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr))** yourself to a file:

```
./myprog 2> myerror.log
```

Then quickly:

```
tail -f myerror.log
```