# need make init.php relation with cores/app.php

Tags: php

I have folder name is like SUPPLIER and inside SUPPLIER I put file php index.php
with the coding like this

```
<?php
    require_once 'apps/init.php';
?>
```

And I add new folder inside SUPPLIER name folder apps, and I put file php init.php inside apps with this code

```
<?php
    require_once 'library/library.php';
    require_once 'cores/app.php';
?>
```

And other rest I'm put on inside folder SUPPLIER/apps I build folder cores. and inside SUPPLIER I put folder library with libary.php inside. And on folder SUPPLIER/apps/cores I put file php with name app.php
When I start running is said

```
This page isn’t working

192.168.40.207 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

When I try put code like this on init.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'library/library.php';
?>
```

It works. But when I try put `require_once 'cores/app.php';` This page isn’t working. I try put code `is_readable('cores/app.php')` the result said `bool(false)`

That's my problem? Can someone help me? I need make init.php relation with cores/app.php

EDIT: I most forgot, the server PHP not from my computer but from others computer, which I can't remote or edit config php.

UPDATE : Never mind, I was wrong. my file cores/app.php caused the error handling.

Comment: error 500 : check your error log

Comment: Also, enable your logs to see directly in the browser
ini_set('display_erros',1);

Comment: @Calimero : How to check log? And i forgot server php location not inside my computer but others computer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834583/where-can-i-find-error-log-files

Comment: @Calimero i cant, cause i dont have authority  to open php.ini :(