# PHP foreach from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am using an api to show a list of times but struggling to display them in using `foreach`

Here is how the data is shown:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2507525
    [snapshotTimes] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-10-02T04:04:41+00:00
            [1] => 2020-10-03T03:22:29+00:00
            [2] => 2020-10-04T03:06:43+00:00
            [3] => 2020-10-04T21:18:11+00:00
            [4] => 2020-10-06T03:07:12+00:00
            [5] => 2020-10-07T03:21:31+00:00
            [6] => 2020-10-10T03:43:00+00:00
            [7] => 2020-10-17T02:58:49+00:00
            [8] => 2020-10-19T02:57:35+00:00
            [9] => 2020-10-23T03:08:28+00:00
            [10] => 2020-10-26T04:02:51+00:00
            [11] => 2020-10-27T04:33:19+00:00
        )

)
```

Code:

```
$domainArray = $services_api->getWithFields("/package/2507525/web/timelineBackup/web");
foreach ($domainArray as $arr) {
    $Time = $arr->$domainArray->snapshotTimes;
    echo " TIME: $Time<br>";
}
```

But it doesn't seem to echo anything at all? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `snapshotTimes` is an array, but you are treating it as if it was a string. you should probably run another inner `foreach` to cycle through all values within `snapshotTimes` .  Check your PHP Error log.

Comment: Perhaps an example would help him @Martin?

Comment: @Vogal oh go on then, if you insist..... see my example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows;

```
$Time = $arr->$domainArray->snapshotTimes;
```

Here you're tying to access a property called `domainArray` on the array given by the `foreach()`. No need to do that since your already using the `foreach()` to loop over the data;

```
$domainArray = $services_api->getWithFields("/package/2507525/web/timelineBackup/web");

// For each item in the 'snapshotTimes' array
foreach ($domainArray->snapshotTimes ?? [] as $time) {
    echo " TIME: {$time}<br>";
}
```

[Try it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9039560bca0973777ee834b124e052c4fe75dd34)

---

**Note:** Using the [null coalescing operator (`?? []`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610622/what-does-double-question-mark-operator-mean-in-php) to ensure `snapshotTimes` exists in the data.

---

Based on comments; the same solution but with [`array_reverse()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to reverse the output.

```
foreach (array_reverse($domainArray->snapshotTimes) as $time) {
    ....
```

[Try it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8434f02a06c77fb378fff82b385eae56a46fba5f)

Comment: Nice use of the `??` operator.

Comment: This is fab, thanks. Is there a way of ordering them in the opposite way? Newest first?

Comment: @Designer Sure there is, take a look at: [`array_reverse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are triying to print snapshotTimes but you created a loop for another thing. If you want to print snapshotTimes code will be like :

```
foreach($arr->$domainArray->snapshotTimes as $time){
    echo $time."</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `snapshotTimes` is an array, but you are treating it as if it was a string. you should probably run another inner foreach to cycle through all values within `snapshotTimes` . Check your PHP Error log.

> Perhaps an example would help him @Martin?

## Example:

```
$domainArray = $services_api->getWithFields("/package/2507525/web/timelineBackup/web");
foreach ($domainArray as $arr) {
   if(is_array($arr->snapshotTimes) && count($arr->snapshotTimes) > 0 ){
    $times = $arr->snapshotTimes;
    foreach($times as $timeRow){
        echo " TIME: ".$timeRow."<br>";
    }
    unset($times); //tidy up temp vars.
    }
}
```

I underline the point that you need to [**check your PHP Error Log**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834583/where-can-i-find-error-log-files) to help you diagnose these sort of structure issues.

## Notes:

- Your reference `$arr->$domainArray->snapshotTimes` within the foreach is incorrect, you're referencing both the foreach label as well as the source of the foreach label, which will result in an error.
- PHP variables should start with a lower case letter.
- If you don't need `$domainArray => $arr` for any other reason within the foreach loop, you can simplify the loop by looping the array rather than the *container*, as [0stone0 shows on their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64562426/3536236).