# Move_uploaded_file() not showing temp_name and others field in php 8.1

Tags: phpexcel, php-8.1, move-uploaded-file

After Upgrading to php 8.1 my `move_uploaded_file` function is not working. Tmp_name is empty and showing Error 6.

I am using PHPExcel. When I uploading it manually my data is fetching correctly but with using `moveuploadedfunction` the file is not moving to the folder. I increase the size of upload file and max post size in php.ini file. Below is the screenshot where tempname and size is showing zero.
[image]

Comment: Show your code, not screenshot of random IDE window

Comment: there are multiples files which files of code should i have to show you?

Comment: Without the function code it is difficult to help you find out what is PHP 7.x compatible and not in PHP 8.x anymore

Comment: @Juan Please tell me which code you want to see? the uplod.php file or the form code?

Comment: Have you restarted your server after update to size limits? How big is your uploaded file? To what limits it's increased? Is it visible in `phpinfo()`? Where is your code that uses `move_uploaded_file`?

Comment: The form code would be useful to see. And post it as text, not as an image.

Comment: check now i edited my question with code.

Comment: That's a lot of code. What **exactly**  is not working with that? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: [**WHAT does your PHP `error_logs` file say?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834583/where-can-i-find-error-log-files-for-php)

Comment: @NicoHaase the only thing that i want is to move excel file.

Comment: In the PHP config, is error handling enabled...? Because errors displayed could help you solve your problem.

Comment: @Juan is there any alternate of uploading file without using move_upload_file function

Comment: Please **don't** share images of code. Share the code **in text form**

Answer (score 0):

The solution that work for me is.
Granted the Full control rights to "C:\Windows\Temp".