# Requiring modules in python

Tags: python

I'm sure this is an extremely simple question, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I'm getting into python and have use a basic 'hello world' router as an example. I wanted to export the majority of the code to expand the app into multiple files. When all of the code is in a single file, it works fine, but when it is moved into 2 separate files, it bombs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

FIRST FILE

```
import re # first file
from Primer.Core.router import Router // second file, excluded when all code is in 1 file

# second file code here when combined

def application(environ, start_response):
    router = Router(environ, start_response)
    return router.run()
```

SECOND FILE

```
from cgi import escape


class Router:

def __init__(self, environ, start_response):
    self.environ = environ
    self.start_response = start_response

def run(self):
    path = self.environ.get('PATH_INFO', '').lstrip('/')
    if (path == 'hello')
        return 'hello'
    else
        return 'other'
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say your code "bombs"? What happens?

Comment: Yup, sorry. I'm running the code in a web browser (via apache) and it returns a 500 error.

Comment: Did you read the Apache logs to find out what's going on?

Comment: Can you check the error log? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731364/internal-error-500-apache-but-nothing-in-the-logs) for more info.

Comment: I've check the error, log, it says 'No module named Primer.Core.router'. Here's my file structure:
index.py is running, then I have ./Primer/Core/router.py. I have __init__.py files in the Primer AND Core directory

Comment: Turns out the issue was I did not have my WSGIPythonPath set in my apache config. I'm still getting used to all this. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 1):

If the two files are in the same directory, you should remove the prefix from the `import`.

```
from router import Router
```

Also, you need to create an empty file `__init__.py` in the directory that contains the file that will be imported.

Comment: They are not in the same folder, and there is an init python file in all directories until the router.py file.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I see several errors in the code:

1. The import will fail as a non-Python comment (`//`) is written after it. You should use `#` instead.
2. You should check that the structure of your files is correct:

   `├── Primer
   │   ├── Core
   │   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   │   └── router.py
   │   ├── __init__.py
   └── index.py`
3. The `if` and `else` in your `Router` class lack both a colon:

   `def run(self):
      path = self.environ.get('PATH_INFO', '').lstrip('/')
      if (path == 'hello'):
          return 'hello'
      else:
          return 'other'`

   Also, the indentation of the methods within your `Router` class is not properly set on your example, but I suppose it is OK in your file...

I'd check that the errors are not due to that first.

Comment: Sorry for the crudeness of the paste, the // comment is not in my actual code (it was meant only for this post). I've double checked the colon and that is not the issue.

Comment: Do you have the index.py file and the Primer folder at the same level? Are you sure the import error comes from the index.py file and not from any other file in another subfolder (which might not be able to locate the router.py file)? With the structure I said before it does not raise any error for me, but of course I have only the code you posted. Maybe if you provide some more code or details we could replicate your problem...