# mydomain.com couldn't handle the request ? Nothing in logs?

Tags: php, apache, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

Hi my websites login page is opening correctly, but when I try to login by putting data in fields it shows error yourdomain.com could not handle the request. HTTP code is 500. After searching over web I found that, might be errors in php code, I have enabled error logging in php. But after looking into files for apache2 error logs & for php no error is logged. To configure the logs I referred this question : [Internal Error 500 Apache, but nothing in the logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731364/internal-error-500-apache-but-nothing-in-the-logs) even then issue persists

What might be the cause ?

Comment: permission not enough, put 755 permission on all scripts you're using

Comment: @MuthaFury Changed permissions by  chmod 755 -R mydir/ but still issue persists, some of the pages are loading some are not.

Comment: I know is a bad idea to do this, try changing to 777, if it is working, probably is the group/owner issue

Comment: if it still doesn't work, then it is your code problem.

Comment: @MuthaFury If code is the cause, nothing is logged in logs for apache2 as well as php, what else I can try ?

Comment: try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on your code

Comment: @MuthaFury Actual error was in code but the files were included, I enabled error reporting in inner file somehow that overridden the final files error reporting. Thanks for the suggestions.