# How do I debug HTTP Error 500 messages when the error_log produces no new entries?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have a website on a live server which works fine.  I have just replaced the old website on the live server with a new website on the live server which is giving me a `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)` messages in the web browser.

The new website works fine on the dev server.

I've checked the error_log file and it is not producing error entries to match the date/time I am getting the `HTTP Error 500` messages.

How do I figure out why this is not working?

---

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: If it's a PHP error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er (obviously you won't know until you look)

Comment: Can you share what your `.htaccess` file looks like?

Comment: Other likely candidates are `.htaccess` screw ups. try removing/commenting out htaccess rules.

Comment: @bjskistad please see `.htaccess` above.

Comment: @Martin please see `.htaccess` above.

Comment: Thanks! Now we should be able to see if this is your error.

Comment: do you mean to not close that final square bracket?

Comment: @Martin, I'd hope so, the old website was using the rewrite engine without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: ahh sorry cross purposes on comments.

Comment: @Martin I appologies, I copied and pasted wrong.  The final bracket was already in the `.htaccess` file.  Corrected above.

Comment: You have two rewriteRules when you only should have one. And the first one appears not to do anything?

Comment: @Martin, I've removed the first rewrite and still have the error message.  However, I have turned on debugging in php.ini and it's now giving me a more details error message.  I guess this question is no longer relevant.  Thanks for the help.  I'll try closing.

Comment: Glad you got a lead on sorting it. don't close it, but not sure if as an author you are still able to mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: @Maybe someone can tell me to turn php debugging on in php.ini? and I could accept? :D  But that's probably cheating...

Comment: @oshirowanen I can look it up for you. :D

Comment: @oshirowanen https://docs.joomla.org/Edit_PHP.INI_File_for_XDebug (Accept now?)

Answer (score 1):

An unlogged 500 error on an apache server almost certainly means there's something wrong with your `.htaccess` file.

Try commenting out a few lines at a time or deleting them from your `.htaccess` file.

Useful further information as to causes of unreported error 500s [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4731364/3536236).

Comment: it doesn't just mean that, but that is a likely cause. The OP was asking for how to debug this cause, rather than fix the problem. How would you go about checking it's  `.htaccess` rather than an issue with an unloaded apache module, for instance?

Comment: @Martin From all of my past experiences with PHP, (and as a PHP dev that's a lot) it has always been the `.htaccess`.

Comment: @Martin If you know any other issue possibilities, feel free to suggest an edit, or comment it.

Comment: Oh yes, me too, but there can be other issues such as apache modules expected but not loaded, I see the question as being more *how* to debug rather than what the cause is in this specific instance. (Sorry I feel I'm being a bit anal here)

Comment: @Martin I see. Before we _can_ debug the error I think they need to share more about their files.