# Unexpected Error 500 running a basic php script that uses WP function

Tags: php, wordpress, centos, whm

I get a 500 HTTP Error (Display Error is enabled) when this script is ran.

centOS 7 latest w/WHM & Wordpress

```
<?php
include 'wp-includes/pluggable.php';
$user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $user
?>
```

Expecting userID echo'd on page. Results in HTTP 500 error. 
Nothing logged in php log.

I looked into wordpress documentations and pluggable.php should be the script to include.

Comment: Check the Wordpress directory for error_log. Sometimes errors are logged there, instead.

Comment: Not sure if this will help but check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731364/internal-error-500-apache-but-nothing-in-the-logs in the `Make sure PHP logging is turned on` section

Comment: Either check error_log in that cPanel's user account where the script is. The location should be `/home/cpaneluser/public_html/error_log`. Also you coudl check `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` to see if any logs are thrown there by apache.