# blank screen in validation after upgrade to laravel 7

Tags: validation, laravel-7

I was upgrading my Laravel 6 to Laravel 7 many days ago and now I uploaded today.
Every things work correctly except validation.

When my form has a wrong data in validation, It return a blank screen.
In some forms such as login and register forms, it return "This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500
"

In my Local host every things work correctly, this mistake just shown in server.

Comment: Check the error log on your server to find details about the 500 error.

Comment: @AdFortia  It is not common 500 error and my error log is empty

Comment: Probably you are not logging this kind of errors. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731364/internal-error-500-apache-but-nothing-in-the-logs

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I had forgotten to upload app/exception/handler.php to my server